# Bug in R e1071 Naive Bayes?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I have no experience in the R community, so please point me somewhere else if this is not the appropriate forum...

Long story short, I'm afraid that `e1071::naiveBayes` favors giving labels by alphabetical order.

In an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897449/strange-results-with-numeric-predictor-in-naive-bayes-in-r) I had noticed some strange behavior with numerical predictors in the `e1071` implementation of naive Bayes.  While I got a more reasonable answer, some probabilities seemed biased upwards.

Can anyone shed any light on why this simulation would end up like this?  I can only imagine that it is a bug at this point...

```
library(e1071)

# get a data frame with numObs rows, and numDistinctLabels possible labels
# each label is randomly drawn from letters a-z
# each label has its own distribution of a numeric variable
# this is normal(i*100, 10), i in 1:numDistinctLabels
# so, if labels are t, m, and q, t is normal(100, 10), m is normal(200, 10), etc
# the idea is that all labels should be predicted just as often
# but it seems that "a" will be predicted most, "b" second, etc

doExperiment = function(numObs, numDistinctLabels){
    possibleLabels = sample(letters, numDistinctLabels, replace=F)
    someFrame = data.frame(
        x=rep(NA, numObs),
        label=rep(NA, numObs)
    )
    numObsPerLabel = numObs / numDistinctLabels
    for(i in 1:length(possibleLabels)){
        label = possibleLabels[i]
        whichAreNA = which(is.na(someFrame$label))
        whichToSet = sample(whichAreNA, numObsPerLabel, replace=F)
        someFrame[whichToSet, "label"] = label
        someFrame[whichToSet, "x"] = rnorm(numObsPerLabel, 100*i, 10)
    }
    someFrame = as.data.frame(unclass(someFrame))
    fit = e1071::naiveBayes(label ~ x, someFrame)
    # The threshold argument doesn't seem to change the matter...
    someFrame$predictions = predict(fit, someFrame, threshold=0)
    someFrame
}

# given a labeled frame, return the label that was predicted most
getMostFrequentPrediction = function(labeledFrame){
    names(which.max(sort(table(labeledFrame$prediction))))
}

# run the experiment a few thousand times
mostPredictedClasses = sapply(1:2000, function(x) getMostFrequentPrediction(doExperiment(100, 5)))

# make a bar chart of the most frequently predicted labels
plot(table(mostPredictedClasses))
```

This gives a plot like:

[image]

Giving every label *the same normal distribution* (i.e. mean 100, stdev 10) gives:

[image]

## Regarding confusion in comment:

This is maybe getting away from Stack Overflow territory here, but anyways...
While I would expect classification to be less clumpy, the effect of the standard deviations does a lot to flatten out the pdfs, and you can observe if you do this enough that one or two actually tend to dominate (red and black in this case).

[image]

Too bad we can't exploit the knowledge that the standard deviation is the same for all of them.

If you add just a little noise to the mean it becomes much more evenly distributed, even though there's still some misclassification.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not `naiveBayes`, it's your `getMostFrequentPrediction` function. You are returning only one value even when there are ties for first. Since you are using `table()`, the counts are being implicitly sorted alphabetically in the table. So when you grab the first max value, it will also be the "smallest" alphabetically speaking. So if you dun this a bunch of times:

```
getMostFrequentPrediction(data.frame(predictions=sample(rep(letters[1:3], 5))))
```

you will *always* get "a" even though the letters "a" "b" and "c" all appear 5 times.

If you want to randomly choose one of the most frequently predicted categories, here's another possible implementation

```
getMostFrequentPrediction = function(labeledFrame){
    tt<-table(labeledFrame$predictions)
    names(sample(tt[tt==max(tt)], 1))
}
```

This gives

[image]

Comment: You are indeed correct about the tie breaking.  Thanks for pointing that out!  I'm trying to recreate something happening on the job where the predominant prediction can be changed by changing the label, but perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: Do you have any explanation as to why removing the 100*i (i.e. giving all labels the same distribution) would remove the effect of this tie breaking?  I would think that there would still be some bias towards letters like a and b, but from my second plot and further tinkering, there is not.

Comment: When you give them all such different distributions (mean =`100*i`, sd=10) they hardly overlap so the categories are much easier to tell apart. Your predictions are nearly perfect so you have a lot of ties. With the complete overlap (mean =`100`, sd=10 for all), you get many fewer ties so the same problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Doh, thanks.  One more thing:  I am experiencing what seems like high "clumping" in the predictions when under identical distributions.  I did 200 "doExperiments" with 100 observations in 5 classes and found that on average the class predicted least has 1.1 observations, 6.3 for the second fewest, ..., and the most predicted class (of 5) has 46.4 rows tied to it on average.  In fact, 70% of the time, one class gets _no_ predictions at all.  (I think putting a "print(tt)" and just rerunning the code will give you the idea). This seems strange...

Comment: Nevermind, I've come to grips with it.  See my update to original question with charts.  Thanks!